# How to save original string into MYSQL after escaped?

Tags: php, mysql

Example:

```
<?php
$uid = 'Pat/r'ick';
$string = mysql_escape_string($uid);

$query = 'INSERT INTO user (uid) VALUES ($string)';

?>
```

After escaped the string, mysql insert value 'Pat//r/'ick' into the table. What I understand is mysql_escape_string is just to escape string so that the query can run without any issue then still should be able to save the original value of the string after escaped. In this case, I expect Mysql to save value 'Pat/r'ick' into the table.

Can someone help me how to save the original string after escaped the string in the query?

Comment: Stop using `mysql`. Move to PDO or mysqli

Comment: If you want to save original string then why you escaping. just put the value in variable and pass that var to query.

Comment: @Rits the variable won't inserted because it contain single quote. As you can see, I'm using php to declare the variable and pass it into mysql query.

Comment: "After escaped the string, mysql insert value 'Pat//r/'ick' into the table" — This seems really unlikely. How are you determining this?

Comment: @Quentin Yes it is. I didn't expect that but it did save the escaped string into the database table.

Comment: @EDDY — What makes you think it is saving the escaped string in the database? How are you examining it? Why is it using a `/` instead of a ```\``` for escaping?

Comment: Your SQL won't even run — you've not put quotes around `$string` and you're using `'` characters so the variable won't be interpolated. You need to provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement which shows the method you are using to examine the database to determine the results.

Comment: @Quentin I'm checking the value from the database and yes, it's storing the escaped string Pat//r/'ick. I've added the ' so it won't interpolated as well. Sorry maybe I might need to create more test data for this to recreate the problem.

Comment: "I'm checking the value from the database" — For the **third time**: HOW?!

Comment: "it's storing the escaped string Pat//r/'ick" — So something is adding **forward** slashes? That won't be anything which escapes the data since escape uses backslashes!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have magic quotes enabled and the string is double quoted. So, turn off magic quotes in the php.ini.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: Magic Quotes haven't been supported by PHP since version 5.3 which has been unsupported (even for security updates) since 2014. Don't turn off magic quotes: **Upgrade to a supported version of PHP**.

Comment: The code in the question shows that the input is coming from a hardcoded string so it wouldn't be passed through the magic quotes engine (it isn't coming from outside the script) so this can't be the answer … except there is so much else about the code in the question that the OP is clearly using an untested overly-simplified example and might be lying about not using external input … and they aren't showing how they are inspecting the data so the escapes might be added when they pull the data out of the database. Maybe. The question is awful.